# Why does $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] return the gateway ip rather than the remote ip with a fortigate router?

Tags: php, ip, firewall, nat

I have a server connected to the internet through a Fortigate 40C. When my php code calls `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`, it returns the ip address of the router (the fortigate) rather than the remote IP accessing the php script.

Why is this?

Comment: It's likely the original IP is still in the request. See if you can find an `X_` header like `X_FORWARDED_FOR`.

Comment: I can confirm this behavior, and add additional info. If the client and the server are on the same VLAN, phpinfo(),  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] and  apache_getenv("REMOTE_ADDR") all report the client IP, but if the client and server are on seperate VLAN's, only the gateway IP shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fortigate has an option to "enable NAT" on a policy, which doesn't mean translate the addresses (it does that for you anyway),  but does mean it alters some packets replacing the remote IP with the gateway IP.

Make sure that "Enable NAT" is disabled, and `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` will work as expected.

Comment: @Simon_eQ The reason I posted this question is I didn't find the answer to this question on stackoverflow and thought it would be useful to others who follow me.

Comment: This indeed was helpful for me :) Thanks for asking and answering your own question!